# Dynamic programming to solve two printers with different speeds

Tags: vb.net, dynamic-programming, memoization

I solved [this problem](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/two-printers) using a Class, but thought I might try to figure out this memoization thing.

> **Problem**
> There are two printers that print pages at different speeds (**X, Y**).
> What is the minimum amount of time it takes to print (**N**) pages?
>
> **Input Data**
>  First line contains the number of test cases 
> Each test case
> is on a new line in the form of **X Y N**
>
> **Output** 
> The minimum printing time for each test case separated by spaces

e.g.

> ```
> input data:
> 2
> 1 1 5
> 3 5 4
>
> output:
> 3 9
> ```

The math here is trickier than it appears, so make the assumption that my math is correct (it is).

#### Code

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On
Option Compare Text

Module Module1

    <STAThread>
    Sub Main()
        Const inputPath As String = "C:\Temp\printers.txt"
        Dim delimiters As String = " " & System.Environment.NewLine
        Dim data() As Integer = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(inputPath).Split(delimiters.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) _
                                .Select(Function(i) Integer.Parse(i)).ToArray
        Dim result As String

        For i As Integer = 0 To data(0) - 1
            result = result & BestTime(data(i * 3 + 1), data(i * 3 + 2), data(i * 3 + 3)) & " "
        Next

        result = result.Trim()
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(inputPath, Environment.NewLine & result)
    End Sub

    Public Function BestTime(ByVal X As Double, ByVal Y As Double, ByVal N As Integer) As Double
        Dim myTimes(1) As Double
        For nextpage As Integer = N To 1 Step -1
            If myTimes(0) + X <= myTimes(1) + Y Then
                myTimes(0) = myTimes(0) + X
            Else
                myTimes(1) = myTimes(1) + Y
            End If
        Next
        Return myTimes.Max
    End Function

End Module
```

For some reason I couldn't get the `delimiters` to work as a constant. I'm using doubles because I kept getting overflow.

---

#### Additional test data

Input

```
16
206 120 2925144
5680 2268 173606
443 144 2231807
1336 1966 235314
251936 215499 755
1 1 610653060
27229864 68593621 7
13 11 58925803
25 13 39786943
936 301 970391
6811369 9145334 90
3070457 3923385 93
111 126 4757640
16350510 10897861 9
171127 91014 3379
2 2 373415582
```

Output

```
221808480 281383956 242540784 187180894 87708093 305326530 137187242 
351099580 340283073 221013936 354191188 160858785 280761012 65387166 
200776884 373415582
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BestTime` method looks great. The `nextpage` variable is never used, so it doesn't really matter which direction the loop goes. I'd be curious why you are using a decrementing loop, but it doesn't matter which direction you use in the grand scheme of things.

---

Choosing `Double` because `Integer` gives you overflow seems misleading. At first I thought "oh good, it handles decimal rates, like 2 1/2 pages per minute". The algorithm looks like it should work for floating point, though.

If you only want to support integral types, you can use `Long` or `ULong`. Based on the test cases you provided, `Long` is sufficient.

---

`myTimes(0) + X` and `myTimes(1) + Y` are calculated twice. For this scale of number it's not a huge performance loss. But if you were extending this to `BigInteger` levels, you could calculate them both once and assign the number if needed.

This is the kind of optimization that would require benchmarking before deciding if it is worthwhile.

---

A `Const` for `delimeters` won't work because `System.Environment.NewLine` is read only property that is not available at compile time. There are a couple of alternatives:

- use a `ReadOnly` field instead of `Const`
- use `vbNewLine` instead of `System.Environment.NewLine`

  - Note, this will (possibly) be different functionality.

However, you only use `delimeters` in one spot, so a method variable like you currently have is fine.

---

You did a good job separating the algorithm from input/output. You could take it further by wrapping input handling in its own function outside of `Main`.

---

If this weren't for a "competition" style of programming, I would recommend a parameter for the input file name so that the user can change it. I'd also strongly encourage a separate parameter for output. Right now, the user needs to perform an extra step before running your program a second time.

Additionally, you could use more descriptive variable names than X, Y, and N. It matches the competition specs so it's perfect in this instance. But for a long term program I would recommend something like printerXSpeed or numberOfPagesToPrint. The caveat is you never know when that one off function you write gets put in production for years.